# Is there any feature to update source code without AppStore review in swift?

Tags: swift

Currently i want to learn that if it's possible to update swift source code without any App Review. As for as i know there is `CodePush` in React Native.

Is there any similar feature in swift for doing it ? Because it's a pain to update minor enhancement using app store review.

Is there any thread that useful for me to learn it ?

Comment: You mean to update source code and provide build to testers without app review from apple, correct?

Comment: @teja_D  no bro, it's not for QA. I talk about production environment. For all users

Comment: @teja_D For example. Next week, one of my button in my mobile apps is remove automatically without any review.  In my case, i'm not able to remove / hide it just by checking the specific date. I need to remove it from the source code. So it needs review to AppStore. But is there any way to use something like `codepush` in react native? As far as i know, `codepush` works to update source code without any review before

Comment: It is not possible without an app review. Still, if you want to make your UI dynamic you can achieve it by implementing API response-based UI

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific feature in Swift that allows for updating source code without an App Review, similar to CodePush in React Native. The App Review process is a requirement for submitting updates to the App Store, and there is currently no way to bypass this process.

However, there are some strategies that can help minimize the time and effort required for App Review. For example, you can use the App Store Connect API to automate the submission process and reduce the need for manual interaction. Additionally, you can use TestFlight to distribute beta versions of your app to internal and external testers, which can help identify and fix any issues before the final submission.

Comment: For my case, the reason is not because issues such as bug. Somehow there are request from users to append or change the wording (information) or message.  So, it requires App Store review?

Comment: Maybe you should just make your text downloadable? Just host it somewhere and update whenever you need.

Comment: @BulatYakupov something like firebase remote config ?

Comment: Yes, for example firebase remote config. I can’t say for sure because I don’t know what exactly is going on in your case :)

Comment: @Suryadi no matter for what purpose, you will need an app store review.